# Oracle/SQL-Need to find the records with exactly same value corresponding to a particular value in other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has the following data:

```
NAME    VALUE

ABC     Y
ABC     Y
ABC     Y
ABC     Y
ABC     Y
DEF     W
DEF     Y
DEF     Y
DEF     Y
DEF     Y
GHI     Y
GHI     Y
GHI     Y
GHI     Y
GHI     Y
```

Now I want to write a query that will return those names where all the values in the rows which have this particular name are the same.

Desirable output is :

```
ABC
GHI
```

Because all the values for ABC and GHI are equal to Y.

Comment: clarified the wording a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
select NAME 
  from YOUR_TABLE
  group by NAME
  having count(distinct VALUE) = 1
     and min(VALUE) = 'Y'
```

Comment: This will also return a name with only value 'N'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates, use `NOT EXISTS` to avoid names with other value than Y.

```
select distinct name
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.name = t2.name
                    and t2.value <> 'Y')
```